# Updating label text in frame when job is finished

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When pressing "Ping test" you get a new 'main window' with input and submit button.
when Submit is clicked, a file is created on the desktop and writes the output result of ping command.
right now, when I enter an address and click submit, I only see the menu frame and the main frame, the output frame shows up when the proccess is finished.

how can I make the output frame show "Pinging..." when I click the Submit button and update the label to "Ping Complete!" when its finished?

here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as sub
import easygui
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

# ===== Frame 1 - Left Menu =====
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Menu",height=80, width=40,
                      padx=5, pady=5, relief="solid")
frame.place(x=10, y=0)

# Show files button
showfilesButton = tk.Button(frame, text="Show Files", padx=5, pady=5,
                            command=lambda: showFiles())
showfilesButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

# ConvertURL button
convertURL = tk.Button(frame, text="Ping Test", padx=5, pady=5,
                       command=lambda: testPing.getURL())
convertURL.grid(row=2, column=0)

# Quit Button
endProgram = tk.Button(frame, text="Quit", padx=5, pady=5,
                       command=lambda: terminate())
endProgram.grid(row=3, column=0)



class testPing():

    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host
        self.clearFile = clearFile
        self.label = label

    def getURL():

        frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Main Window", height=350, width=300, padx=30, pady=30)
        frame2.pack()

        urlLabel = tk.Label(frame2, text="Enter URL : ", padx=5, pady=5)
        urlLabel.place(x=-30, y=-30)
        urlInputBox = tk.Entry(frame2)
        urlInputBox.pack()

        clearLabel = tk.Label(frame2, text="Clear File?", padx=5, pady=5)
        clearLabel.place(x=-30, y=20)

        clearFile = tk.BooleanVar()
        clearFile.set(False)
        clearFileRadioYes = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="yes", value=True, var=clearFile,
                                           command=lambda: testPing.callback(clearFile.get()))
        clearFileRadioYes.place(x=-30, y=45)

        clearFileRadioNo = tk.Radiobutton(frame2, text="no", value=False, var=clearFile,
                                          command=lambda: testPing.callback(clearFile.get()))
        clearFileRadioNo.place(x=20, y=45)

        urlSubmitButton = tk.Button(frame2, text="Submit",
                                    command=lambda: testPing.pingURL(urlInputBox.get(), clearFile.get()))
        urlSubmitButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    def callback(clearFile):

        bul = clearFile
        print(bul)

    def pingURL(host, clearFile):

        outputLabel = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Output", height=35, width=150,
                               padx=5, pady=5, relief="solid")
        outputLabel.place(x=0, y=150)
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/ping.txt'
        label = tk.Label(outputLabel, text=f'Pinging {host} ...')
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        clear = clearFile

        if clear == True:
            with open(file, 'w+') as output:
                output.truncate(0)
                sub.call(['ping', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

        else:
            with open(file, 'a') as output:
                sub.call(['ping', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

        output.close()
        # testPing.changeLabel(host)

    def changeLabel(host):

        myLabel = tk.Label.config(text=f"Ping to {host} Complete!")
        myLabel.pack()

def terminate():
    exit()

def showFiles():

    path = easygui.diropenbox()  # Opens a folder dialog box.
    folder = path
    filelocation = f"c:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\Desktop\\showFilesResult.txt"
    filenames = os.listdir(folder)  # Get the file names in the folder.

    # Writing to file
    with open(filelocation, 'a') as file:
        for name in filenames:
            file.write(f"Name: {name}\nFolder Path: {folder}\n!------------------------------!\n")

    print("Done!")


root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `changeLabel()`, you can simply put:

```
output.close()
label.configure(text=f'Ping to {host} complete!')
# testPing.changeLabel(host)
```

But remember about updating your label first, if you don't at the end only complete label will be visible.

```
label = tk.Label(outputLabel, text=f'Pinging {host} ...')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
label.update()
```

An additional tip, don't use different GUI creators in one project. If you only using easygui to get the path, *check Tkinter methods -> [askopenfilename and asksaveasfilename](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm).*